# Icon not showing up when placed after <ul>

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to put an icon at the end of my navigation bar. 
When I put it before my ul tags, it shows up, according to this code:

```html
<div class="navigation"> 
                 <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                  
                <ul>
                <li class="menu active"><a href="discover.html">Discover</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="fashion.html">Fashion</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="portraits.html">Creative portraits</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="client.html">Client work</a></li>
                <br>
                <br>
                
                <li class="contact"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            
                <br>
                <br>
               
                 
                </div>
```

However, as soon as I place the icon after, it does not show up, as demonstrated in this code.

```html
<div class="navigation"> 
                 
                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
            
                <ul>
                <li class="menu active"><a href="discover.html">Discover</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="fashion.html">Fashion</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="portraits.html">Creative portraits</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="client.html">Client work</a></li>
                <br>
                <br>
                
                <li class="contact"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            
                <br>
                <br>
               <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 
                </div>
```

What can I do to make it appear??

Comment: Tested this in a fiddle using a fa cdn and I am getting both icons.    Can you provide more details/css for your navigation classes

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, see below. Maybe you should add your CSS to find the problem.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navigation">

  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>

  <ul>
    <li class="menu active"><a href="discover.html">Discover</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="fashion.html">Fashion</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="portraits.html">Creative portraits</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="client.html">Client work</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>

    <li class="contact"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <br>
  <br>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine. Add font awesome CDN `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">`
. This will work for you